# POWER BI - DAX - Measure filter

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax, ssas

I have a dax measure . This measure have 1 data . This is "GOOGLE";"YOUTUBE";"AMAZON"

I want to use this 1 line string result in FILTER.

**CALCULATE(SUM(_TABLE);_TABLE.COMPANIESNAME; FILTER(_TABLE.COMPANIESNAME IN { mymeasure } ))**

Does anyone can help me solve this problem ?

Thank you for help

Comment: your dax measure produce one record consisting of 3 values?

Comment: what is your dax measure?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably way better ways to do what you want. You are treating Power BI like a relational database when you should be using it like a Star Schema. But without more info, I'm just going to answer the question.

Here's my sample table:

```
// Table
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcsxNrMrPU9JRMlSK1YlWcs/PT89JBXKNwNzI/NKQ0iQQ3xjMd0tMTk3Kz88GCpgoxcYCAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Company = _t, Count = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Count", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

[image: Data table]

I don't have your DAX measure or its name, so I'm using this:

```
CompanyList = """Google"";""YouTube"";""Amazon"""
```

Just to prove it's the same as your measure, here it is in the report:
[image: Measure in a card on the report]

From [this post](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/DAX-To-Split-Measure-Text-into-Separate-Rows/m-p/2298395) I created a DAX formula that will parse your DAX value into a table with one row for each company name. Add this as a DAX table from **Modeling > New Table**. I named mine "Filtered table".

```
Filtered table = VAR CommaSeparatedList = [CompanyList]
VAR BarSeparatedList =
    SUBSTITUTE ( CommaSeparatedList, ";", "|" )
VAR Length =
    PATHLENGTH ( BarSeparatedList )
VAR Result =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        GENERATESERIES ( 1, Length ),
        "Company", SUBSTITUTE( PATHITEM ( BarSeparatedList, [Value] ), """", "")
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Here's what the table looks like:

[image: Filtered table]

Add a relationship between the two tables like this (**Modeling > Manage relationships > New...**):
[image: Add relationship]

Then add a DAX column to the filtered table by selecting the table and then **Modeling > New Column**

```
Count = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Count]))
```

[image: Table with Count added]

You can total it up with this DAX measure:

```
Filtered total = SUM('Filtered table'[Count])
```

[image: Final result]

Change the CompanyList measure, and result will update:
[image: Changed measure]